# C - Weird error when trying to take mod of 2 numbers

Tags: c, function

I'm kind of new to C so I'm having trouble with all of its intricacies. In this function, I am trying to find the number of days in a month, including leap years. My problem comes in the second else statement when I try to take the mod of 2 numbers. Any help? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int length(int month, int year)
{
    int monthday;

    if (month == 2) {
        if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0))) {
            monthday = 29;
        } else {
            monthday = 28;
        }
    } else {
        monthday = (30 + (month + floor((month / 8))) % 2);
    }
    return monthday;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Whatever the error is, `floor()` is completely meaningless here as you're only working with integers. I assume it is indeed the source of the error, as it returns a `double`. Just try `30 + (month + month/8) % 2`

Comment: @Mureinik the error is in the monthday =  statement.

Comment: @FelixPalmen so I will technically always be getting the floor of the number? If not, how else can I implement that?

Comment: @flarp can you include the error's text please?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p6

Comment: @flarp, there are only whole numbers in `int`. `8` is an `int` literal (you would have to write `8.0` for a `double` literal). dividing two `int`s results in an `int` (integer division).

Comment: @FelixPalmen that's what I meant by C's intricacies :P Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nerdistcolony could you *please* not needlessly change coding style in an edit? thanks!

Comment: @FelixPalmen Why? I went into fix the error around the != and made other incidental fixes. Please show the harm, if any.  The code is more readable now. It is improved. No harm.

Comment: @nerdistcolony 1. there was no error. 2. repairing indentation and spacing is fine, but to me, the result of your edit is *less* readable. People prefer different bracing styles and as long as it is consistently applied, please don't mess with it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I guess that's fair. From my standpoint, I will *never* see the sense in a bracing style that overloads the code with whitespace and stretches it vertically and requires excess scrolling so you can't see your code in one (or minimal pages). It just looks gaudy to an extreme to me, and I'm not even a guy who likes to compress things. Some whitespace is great, but that's ludicrous. Worked in a kernel group and seen too much kernel and other C code, where they have no patience for the style you consider unreadable though they were total sticklers for coding standards for readability

Comment: @nerdistcolony discussing this in detail would get to "meta" soon, just [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) for proposed advantages. I think any *consistent* (and well-known) style is fine in code snippets on here.

Answer (score 0):

The mod operand only accepts two integers. The function `floor` returns a double, so that's where the error is originating from.

Please replace that line with

```
monthday = (30 + (month + month/8)%2);
```

You do not need the `floor` function, because, dividing two integers in C give you an integer as a result, which is the floor of the result.

By trying to compile a program with this function, I get this error:

> test.c:21:52: error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘double’ and ‘int’)
>            monthday = (30 + (month + floor((month/8)))%2);